# Other ways besides USPS/FedEx/etc to deposit LARGE checks into online banks?

Tags: united-states, check, online-banking, deposits

Mobile Deposit is great and all, but most mobile apps have pretty low deposit limits.  Even though Ally's limit is high ($50,000), checks can of course be higher.

Thus, what's the alternative to posting the check via registered service (which costs money)?

Comment: Does your online bank require a linked account from a bricks-and-mortar bank?

Comment: @Lawrence not that I've heard.

Comment: Have you asked your online bank what their alternatives are? Or what deposit channels they make available?

Comment: Since you apparently don't have another checking or savings account in a bricks-and-mortar bank, have you considered asking whomsoever is sending you checks for large amounts of money if they can do an ACH transfer directly into your online bank account? They may prefer such online transfers since it likely saves _them_ money and postage too, as well as the possible hassle if the check is lost in the mail. Of course, if by large check you mean the kind that PCH delivers in a videotaped transaction at your front door.....

Comment: @DilipSarwate I bank with Chase, but am asking about people who don't.  (My large checks are things like proceeds from the sale of a house.)

Comment: I have never gotten a paper check from sale of a house. It's always been wired from the escrow company into my account.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus lawyers must be old fashioned where I live... :(

Answer (score 2):

The alternative is to use a close by bank or credit union then electronically lnk the two accounts and make a transfer.

Keep in mind that large checks may have different holding periods. The bank may also limit the number of checks deposited or the number of transactions in a month.

Comment: That's what I do. There are people, though, who have migrated away from b-and-m.

Answer (score 1):

Since the proceeds are from a large transaction such as a house sale, one option is to ask the settlement agent (or similar) to do the remittance by internet transfer to the bank account directly.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't terribly helpful generally and feels like a product plug but I just opened a checking account at Schwab, my box of checks included five postage paid envelopes to facilitate paper check deposits.  I don't know if Ally, or any other bank, does something similar.

Comment: Parcel post is what I'm looking to avoid.

Comment: @RonJon, understood, I thought you were trying to avoid the cost of parcel post.

Comment: I don't want to pay, but even less do I want it to get lost!!  :)

Comment: If it matters, Schwab also has a spattering of physical locations.  (I can't say enough good things about my experiences with Schwab, and Ally for that matter)